# C++ OpenCV imdecode slow

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, jpeg, bmp

I send a byte array of an image from C# to a C++ Library. I decode the image with OpenCV (Version 3.3.1) BMP images are fast in decoding but JPEG images are slow.

How i can speed up the decoding time for JPEG images? (Multithreading, GPU, ...?)

**Performance of decode**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| Resolution | Format | Size  | Duration  |             |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 800x600    | BMP    | 2MB   | 0.7 ms    |             |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 800x600    | JPEG   | 10KB  | 4 ms      | 500% slower |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

**OpenCV C++ Method**

```
VMAPI char* __stdcall SendImage(unsigned char* pArray, int nSize)
{
    cv::Mat buf(1, nSize, CV_8UC1, (void*)pArray);
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    //cv::Mat input = cv::imdecode(buf, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv::Mat input = cv::imdecode(buf, -1);
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;
    std::string result = "Test Version 1.0 - Elapsed time: " + std::to_string(elapsed.count() * 1000) + " s\n";

    return _strdup(result.c_str());
}
```

**C# Request**

```
[DllImport("VideoModule.dll")]
public static extern string SendImage(IntPtr pArray, int nSize);

static void ProcessImage()
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(800, 600);
    using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        graphic.Clear(Color.White);
        graphic.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.DarkBlue), 20, 20, 60, 60);
        graphic.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.DarkGreen), 200, 200, 60, 60);
        graphic.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red), 500, 400, 60, 60);
    }

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    //Return an image in JPEG
    bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    //Return an image in BMP
    //bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    var imageData = memoryStream.GetBuffer();

    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(imageData[0]) * imageData.Length;
    IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

    try
    {
        // Copy the array to unmanaged memory.
        Marshal.Copy(imageData, 0, pnt, imageData.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    result = SendImage(pnt, imageData.Length);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: JPG format uses compress algorithm to reduce the image size, while usually BMP does not.

Comment: I know but 500% difference? And the similar problem in C# jpeg wins?

Comment: Are you running a debug release? What optimisation options did you use for compiling?

Comment: Its run in release mode, how i can check which optimisation are active? `/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\opencv\opencv331\opencv\build\include" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "VIDEOMODULE_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\VideoModule.pch" /diagnostics:classic `

Comment: "I know but 500% difference?" [Decoding JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Decoding) is somewhat more involved than simply copying and shuffling the raw image data stored in BMP. The extra complexity is what you pay for needing only 0.5% of the space to store that image. | That said, I'm rather puzzled as to why you encode/decode at all in the scenario you show us (not to mention JPEG being far from ideal format for the type of image you've got).

Comment: People may mistakenly believe that the slowest part of loading an image is reading from the disk. It generally isn't (although at times it can take much longer than usual), for a JPEG the disk reading part is maybe a tenth of the time it takes, the rest is decoding. In other words disk IO is generally fast enough that you should expect uncompressed images to load faster despite being larger on the disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a other codec for example

- https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo
- http://www.fastcompression.com/news/2013-cuda-jpeg-codec.htm
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp

An interesting article on this Topic
http://www.briancbecker.com/blog/2010/analysis-of-jpeg-decoding-speeds/

Build OpenCV 3.0.0 with libjpeg turbo?
http://answers.opencv.org/question/68681/how-to-build-opencv-300-with-libjpeg-turbo/