# python opencv create image from bytearray

Tags: opencv, python-3.7

I am capturing video from a Ricoh Theta V camera. [It delivers the video as Motion JPEG (MJPEG)](https://developers.google.com/streetview/open-spherical-camera/reference/camera/getlivepreview). To get the video you have to do an HTTP POST alas which means I cannot use the `cv2.VideoCapture(url)` feature.

So the way to do this per numerous posts on the web and SO is something like this:

```
bytes = bytes()
while True:
    bytes += stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
    if a != -1 and b != -1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes = bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('i', i)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            exit(0)
```

That actually works, except it is slow. I'm processing a 1920x1080 jpeg stream. on a Mac Book Pro running OSX 10.12.6. The call to `imdecode` takes approx 425000 microseconds to process each image

Any idea how to do this without `imdecode` or make `imdecode` faster? I'd like it to work at 60FPS with HD video (at least).

I'm using Python3.7 and OpenCV4.

Comment: Related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994538/c-opencv-imdecode-slow)

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Again**

I looked into JPEG decoding from the memory buffer using PyTurboJPEG, the code goes like this to compare with OpenCV's `imdecode()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
from turbojpeg import TurboJPEG, TJPF_GRAY, TJSAMP_GRAY

# Load image into memory
r = open('image.jpg','rb').read()
inp = np.asarray(bytearray(r), dtype=np.uint8)

# Decode JPEG from memory into Numpy array using OpenCV
i0 = cv2.imdecode(inp, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Use default library installation
jpeg = TurboJPEG()

# Decode JPEG from memory using turbojpeg
i1 = jpeg.decode(r)
cv2.imshow('Decoded with TurboJPEG', i1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And the answer is that TurboJPEG is 7x faster! That is 4.6ms versus 32.2ms.

```
In [18]: %timeit i0 = cv2.imdecode(inp, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)                                           
32.2 ms ± 346 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit i1 = jpeg.decode(r)                                                                
4.63 ms ± 55.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Kudos to @Nuzhny for spotting it first!

**Updated Answer**

I have been doing some further benchmarks on this and was unable to verify your claim that it is faster to save an image to disk and read it with `imread()` than it is to use `imdecode()` from memory. Here is how I tested in IPython:

```
import cv2

# First use 'imread()'

%timeit i1 = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
116 ms ± 2.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Now prepare the exact same image in memory
r = open('image.jpg','rb').read()  
inp = np.asarray(bytearray(r), dtype=np.uint8)

# And try again with 'imdecode()'
%timeit i0 = cv2.imdecode(inp, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
113 ms ± 1.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So, I find `imdecode()` around 3% faster than `imread()` on my machine. Even if I include the `np.asarray()` into the timing, it is still quicker from memory than disk - and I have seriously fast 3GB/s NVME disks on my machine...

**Original Answer**

I haven't tested this but it seems to me that you are doing this in a loop:

```
read 1k bytes
append it to a buffer
look for JPEG SOI marker (0xffdb)
look for JPEG EOI marker (0xffd9)
if you have found both the start and the end of a JPEG frame, decode it
```

1) Now, most JPEG images with any interesting content I have seen are between 30kB to 300kB so you are going to do 30-300 append operations on a buffer. I don't know much abut Python but I guess that may cause a re-allocation of memory, which I guess may be slow.

2) Next you are going to look for the **SOI** marker in the first 1kB, then again in the first 2kB, then again in the first 3kB, then again in the first 4kB - even if you have already found it!

3) Likewise, you are going to look for the **EOI** marker in the first 1kB, the first 2kB...

So, I would suggest you try:

1) allocating a bigger buffer at the start and acquiring directly into it at the appropriate offset

2) not searching for the **SOI** marker if you have already found it - e.g. set it to `-1` at the start of each frame and only try and find it if it is still `-1`

3) only look for the **EOI** marker in the new data on each iteration, not in all the data you have already searched on previous iterations

4) furthermore, actually, don't bother looking for the **EOI** marker unless you have already found the **SOI** marker, because the end of a frame without the corresponding start is no use to you anyway - it is incomplete.

I may be wrong in my assumptions, (I have been before!) but at least if they are public someone cleverer than me can check them!!!

Comment: The performance issue is with `cv2.imdecode`. That is the question I want answered in any event. Maybe I didn't make that clear? If I write to disk and read back from disk instead of doing `imdecode` it is much faster. I wonder who/what is doing the decoding on the write/read operation. The OS?

Comment: When I have time I‘ll double -check my claim about imread. But nonetheless by your own timings above you can not even get  10 frames a second using imdecode. That is not very good for video! And we are processing a video feed. That’s assuming the python code is as fast as possible which it may not be as you say. So again imdecode is not able to process an MJPeg video stream at faster than 10 FPS

Comment: The image I was testing with actually had unusually high entropy. I just tried it again with a lower entropy, more normal image and both methods took around 30ms corresponding to 30+ fps. Furthermore, this is just sequential code, if you used multi-threading or multi-processing you could potentially increase the frame rate by a factor of maybe 2-4 times on most modern, multi-core desktops.

Comment: I'm processing a 1920x1080 jpeg stream. on a macbookpro. OSX 10.12.6. It takes imdecode approx 425000 microseconds to process each image.

Comment: Pls forget my comment about reading/writing being faster. That is a red herring. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use turbo-jpeg. It has a python API: [PyTurboJPEG](https://pypi.org/project/PyTurboJPEG/).

Comment: This can be a comment rather than an answer.